# I need that when i chose a price from html paypal form it will automatically fill the price on Paypal?

Tags: php, html, paypal

I need that when i chose a price from html paypal form it will automatically fill the price on Paypal? How is it possible need help

Answer (score -1):

Can you be more precise?

**Form Attributes — ACTION and METHOD**

The FORM tag includes two required attributes, action and method, which always look like this:

```
<FORM action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```

> Important: Do not change these values. These attributes are required
>   for all payment buttons and the Cart Upload command.

**Hidden Input Variables**

HTML input variables in a PayPal Payments Standard FORM are always hidden from the payer's view. They have the following general format:

```
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="variableName" value="allowedValue">
```

> The `variableName` is any of the variables described in HTML Variables
>   for PayPal Payments Standard," and the allowedValue is any of the
>   values detailed for those variables.

**Specifying the Kind of Payment Button — cmd**

The cmd variable is always required in a FORM. Its value determines which PayPal Payments Standard checkout experience you are using to obtain payment.